# How to create/edit excel by office open xml standard

Tags: c#, excel

#### What I have searched & read:

- [C# .xml to .xlsx how? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649886/c-sharp-xml-to-xlsx-how)
- [.net - How do I create an Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C# without installing Microsoft Office? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic)

#### What I have tried:

I have tried to parse the xml to a DataTable and then create/edit excel using EPPlus.
But the excel xml format depends on the API.

#### What I expect:

e.g.: if there is a xml text like:

```xml
<excel>
    <name>demo</name>
    <Workbook>
        <sheet name='sheet1'>
            <Row>
                <Cell>ID</Cell>
                <Cell>Name</Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>1</Cell>
                <Cell>Wei</Cell>
            </Row>          
        </Sheet>
        <sheet name='sheet2'>
            ...
        </Sheet>        
    </Workbook>
</excel>
```

I expect some method to parse xmlText to excel

```
var xmlText = @"<excel>...</excel>";
var excel = SomeExcelTool.Parse(xmlText);
```

If such a method exists, where can I search the standard xml format for excel?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk